# Finding $E(\hat{p})$ and $V(\hat{p})$ of a sample proportion

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, variance, sampling

Consider a population of nine taxpayers.  Suppose five of the taxpayers are Democrats and the rest Republican.

Consider all SRS of size $n = 3$.

a. Find the sampling distribution of $\hat{p}$, the proportion of Democrats in the sample.

b. Using the sampling distribution, find $E(\hat{p})$ and $V(\hat{p})$.

c. Is $\hat{p}$ an unbiased estimator of $p$, the population proportion?  Why or why not?

d. Verify that $V(\hat{p})$ computed using the sampling distribution equals:

${N-n}\over{N-1}$$\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ = ${N-n}\over{N-1}$$\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$

**Attempted Solution:**

a. $5\over9$

b. The probability of choosing $0, 1, 2$, and $3$ democrats from a sample of three are

${\binom{5}{0}\binom{4}{3}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$, ${\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$, ${\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$, ${\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{0}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$

The value of $\hat{p}$ that we would associate each of these with would be $0$, $1\over3$, $2\over3$, and $3\over3$.

Then, multiplying each $p$ with its respective $\hat{p}$ and summing, we get

${\binom{5}{0}\binom{4}{3}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$$(0)$ + ${\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$$(\frac{1}{3})$ + ${\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$$(\frac{2}{3})$ + ${\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{0}}\over{9 \choose {3}}$$(\frac{3}{3})$ = $5\over9$ which is the same value that I got in part a.

$V(\hat{p})$ = ${{\binom{5}{0}\binom{4}{3}}\over{9 \choose {3}}}^2$$(0)$ +        ${{\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}}\over{9 \choose {3}}}^2$$(\frac{1}{3})$ + 
${{\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}}\over{9 \choose {3}}}^2$$(\frac{2}{3})$ + 
${{\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{0}}\over{9 \choose {3}}}^2$$(\frac{3}{3})$ - $(\frac{5}{9})^2$ = $-0.1$

c. Since $\hat{p}$ = $p$ = $5\over9$, then $\hat{p}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$.

d. Need to find $V(\hat{p})$ to answer this but I have that

${N-n}\over{N-1}$$\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$ = ${9-3}\over{9-1}$$\frac{\frac{5}{9}\frac{4}{9}}{3}$

Comment: Please use display-style [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) by delimiting the markdown with `$$` on either side as opposed to `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) To "find the sampling distribution" actually means to do something you've done in part (b), which is to list out the values that $\hat p$ can be along with their associated probabilities.

(b) To calculate $V(\hat p)$, first recall that for any random variable $X$, we have $V(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$. You've already done the hard part, which is finding the distribution of $\hat p$; now, compute $E[\hat p^2]$ as
$$\frac{\binom 5 0 \binom 4 3}{\binom 9 3} (0)^2 + \frac{\binom 5 1 \binom 4 2}{\binom 9 3} (\frac 1 3)^2 + \dots$$
and then subtract $(5/9)^2$ from this.

(c) What you mean is that $E[\hat p] = p$. Remember that $p$ is a fixed number, which in this case is $\frac 5 9$, and that $\hat p$ is a *random variable* because it depends on the sample. Sometimes it will be $0$, sometimes it will be $2/3$, etc. -- but on average, it is indeed $5/9$.

(d) You should now be in a position to verify this.

Comment: I'm getting a negative variance?

Comment: Uh-oh! Can you show your work? (Make sure you include the terms I obscured with $\dots$ in my original answer....)

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: I might have made a mistake in excel.

Comment: Might it be the case that I should square 0, 1/3, 2/3, and 3/3 instead?

Comment: Whoops! Yep, sorry. Boneheaded mistake on my part. I'll fix my post.

Comment: I'm getting a variance of 1.024 now so that looks pretty good. Actually, I don't think that equals the variance in part d.

Comment: Never mind! It's right.